# How do I reduce the number of search units in Azure cognitive search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

How do I reduce the number of search units in Azure cognitive search? I mistakenly overprovisioned the capacity and I no longer need as many search units. Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-capacity-planning#add-or-reduce-replicas-and-partitions?

Answer (score 0):

You can scale down your search service units by reducing the number of partitions or replicas. See below docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-capacity-planning#add-or-reduce-replicas-and-partitions